# How to merge two tables in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Hi I am new to spot fire. with spot fire (6.5 version)I have to connect to two tables which are from two different data sources. I need to create one calculated column which contains the columns from both tables. but at a time I am able to derive the formula using one data source columns only.

I  need to compare the two columns from two different data sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are trying to combine data from two different data sources make sure that you have a common column to join.There is an option Insert->Columns using which you can bring columns from a different source.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply.this is really  helpful to me .Tq Akshaya Bhat

Answer (score 0):

Here I mentioned the steps in detail for performing the JOIN operation in spot fire.go through [Spot fire JOINS operation](http://goo.gl/z2EEqT) Link.